# How to rename pattern in one file to another over several directories recursively

Tags: bash, rename, recursive

I have several directories through which I want to recursively iterate over and change the file name of

> *.GEOT14246.*

to

> *.GEOT15000.*

Is there a one liner on the bash script to do this or do I have to the write a script with a for loop. My try (which doesn't work) is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in `find . -type f -name "*.GEOT14246.*"`  
do
    echo "file = $file"
    mv $file *.GEOT15000.*
done
```

I then call with:

```
cd /path/to/script/
sh ./script1.sh /path/to/starting/dir
```

Obviously this doesn't work because I don't think I'm passing the starting directory path as an argument. I'm very new to Unix, so how can I pass arguments to it to say from which directory it should start searching and how do I get the script to work?

Comment: Will this answer help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4794313/1119381

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
find . -type f -name "*.GEOT14246.*" -print0 | \
xargs -0 rename 's/GEOT14246/GEOT15000/'
```

given there is not directories named *`*.GEOT14246.*`*

---

A bash variant using find could be something like:

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    printf "MV: %-40s => %s\n" "$file" "${file/GEOT14246/GEOT15000}"
    mv "$file" "${file/GEOT14246/GEOT15000}"
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.GEOT14246.*" -print0)
              |                                 |
              +--- this is starting directory   +--- This ensures no hiccup
                                                     if newline etc. in name
```

Relative, but full, paths are passed from find – which you should see from the
`printf` statement.

The new name is compiled by using bash:

```
${some_variable/find/replace}
```

to replace all `find`'s use:

```
${some_variable//find/replace}
```

etc. [More here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html). This could also be a good read: *[BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)*, *[UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind)*.

Read some guides like [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide). Find some tutorials on-line, but usually never trust them, ask here or on irc.freenode.net #bash.

---

You do not need to invoke the script by calling `sh`. That would also call Bourne shell (sh) and not Bourne Again shell (bash). If you intend to run it with bash; issue `bash file`. `.sh` extension is also out of place.

What you normally do is make the file executable by:

```
chmod +x script_file
```

and then run it with:

```
./script_file
```

The *shebang* takes care of what environment the script should run in.

---

In your script you do not use the passed path-name anywhere. The script has
a "argument list" starting from `$0` which is the script name, `$1` first argument, `$2` second, - and so on.

In your script you would do something in the direction of:

```
# Check if argument 1 is a directory, if not exit with error
if ! [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
    printf "Usage: %s [PATH]\n" "$(basename "$0")" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# OK
path="$1"

while ...

done < <(find "$path" -type f ...)
```

---

Your current `mv` statement would move all files to wherever you issue the command – to one file named *.GEOT14246.* (as in overwrite for each `mv` statement):

Before script run:

```
$ tree
.
└── d1
    ├── a1
    │   ├── a2
    │   │   ├── a3
    │   │   │   └── foo.GEOT14246.faa
    │   │   └── foo.GEOT14246.faa
    │   └── foo.GEOT14246.faa
    └── b1
        ├── b2
        │   ├── b3
        │   │   └── foo.GEOT14246.faa
        │   └── foo.GEOT14246.faa
        └── foo.GEOT14246.faa
```

After script run:

```
$ tree
.
├── d1
│   ├── a1
│   │   └── a2
│   │       └── a3
│   └── b1
│       └── b2
│           └── b3
└── *.GEOT15000.*
```

Also files / paths with spaces or other funny things would make the script go bad and spread havoc. Therefor you have to quote your variables (such as `"$file"`).

Answer (score 2):

In bash 4.0 or later you could also use globstar:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*GEOT14246*; do mv "$f" "$f{/14246/15000}"; done
rename s/14246/15000/ **/*GEOT14246*
```

- The glob pattern also matches folders that contain GEOT14246
- Both options apply to the whole path
- There can be an argument list too long error if the glob pattern is expanded to be longer than `getconf ARG_MAX`

Or using find and read:

```
find . -name '*GEOT14246*' | while read f; do mv "$f" "${f/14246/15000}"; done
```

- `-print0` is not needed if the paths don't contain linefeeds
- `IFS=` is not needed if the paths don't start or end with characters in IFS
- `-r` is not needed if the paths don't contain backslashes
- `< <()` is not needed if you don't modify variables outside the while loop or something

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple one-liner in bash, but there is one in zsh. Add the line `autoload -U zmv` to your `~/.zshrc`. Then you can use [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) and zsh's [wildcards](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) and [parameter substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion).

```
zmv '/path/to/starting/dir/**/*GEOT14246*' '${f//GEOT14246/GEOT15000}'
```

Note that this replaces `GEOT14246` in file names as well. You need the quotes around both arguments because `zmv` parses them again.

On Linux, with bash or zsh, you can use [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) instead. This replaces only the first occurrence of `GEOT14246` in each path.

```
rename GEOT14246 GEOT15000 /path/to/starting/dir/**/*GEOT14246*
```

In bash, you need to enable the `**` recursive glob first with `shopt -s globstar` (add this line to your `~/.bashrc`).

If your Linux distribution is Debian, Ubuntu or a derivative, the [`rename`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=prename&sektion=1) command is a different one. Use either of these:

```
rename.ul GEOT14246 GEOT15000 /path/to/starting/dir/**/*GEOT14246*
rename 's/GEOT14246/GEOT15000/g' /path/to/starting/dir/**/*GEOT14246*
```